# Seeing Server Logs on Discord Channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I own a server in a game. It saves server logs in **.txt** format. What I want to do is to send that change to the discord channel whenever there is a change in the server logs. I'm building my Discord bot with Node.js. Is there any way to this?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I get what you're trying to achieve here but I guess you could always just use document history and check what the last line in that text file is and if it does ***not*** match (that would mean it has already been posted) you send the line to the channel in the form you want (message, embed, etc.)

Also, to check when the file has been changed you can either integrate with the bot or listen to changes in some other manner.